# How to add redirect link in jenkins Groovy Postbuild Plugin?

Tags: jenkins

I want to create a link for redirection to a web URL using the Groovy Postbuild Plugin in a pipeline job.
the purpose is to put the link next to the build in the build history so when I click it it will be redirecting me to the specified URL (which is a certain environment variable from the build itself).

To add a simple text I can just use this:

```
manager.addShortText("${HTTP_URL}", "black", "white", "1px", "blue");
```

But, How do I add the **href** like I do in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,
So I found out how to do it,
need to use the manager.addShortText module to receive an argument with the reference inside it.

```
stage('postbuild display google link') {
    String HTTP_URL= "www.google.com"
    description = "<a href='${HTTP_URL}'</a>" + "google"
    manager.addShortText(description, "black", "white", "1.5px", "white");
}
```